Symmetry properties of spin Berry curvature in time-reversal symmetric systems
I know that the usual charge Berry curvature $\mathbf{\Omega}_n(\mathbf{k})$,
$$
\mathbf{\Omega}_n(\mathbf{k}) = i\sum_{m\ne n}\frac{\langle u_{n,{\mathbf{k}}}| \partial_\mathbf{k} H(\mathbf{k})|  u_{m,{\mathbf{k}}} \rangle \times \langle u_{m,{\mathbf{k}}}| \partial_\mathbf{k} H(\mathbf{k})|  u_{n,{\mathbf{k}}} \rangle}{(E_{m,\mathbf{k}} - E_{n,\mathbf{k}})^2},
$$
satisfies the following symmetry relation in time-reversal symmetric systems:
$$
\mathbf{\Omega}_n(\mathbf{k}) = - \mathbf{\Omega}_n(-\mathbf{k}).
$$
I wonder, what relation does the spin Berry curvature $\mathbf{\Omega}_n^\gamma(\mathbf{k})$ satisfy in such systems? The spin Berry curvature is defined as
$$
\mathbf{\Omega}_n^\gamma(\mathbf{k}) = i\sum_{m\ne n}\frac{\langle u_{n,{\mathbf{k}}}| {S}^{\gamma}\partial_\mathbf{k} H(\mathbf{k})|  u_{m,{\mathbf{k}}} \rangle \times \langle u_{m,{\mathbf{k}}}| \partial_\mathbf{k} H(\mathbf{k})|  u_{n,{\mathbf{k}}} \rangle}{(E_{m,\mathbf{k}} - E_{n,\mathbf{k}})^2},
$$
where $S^\gamma$ is the spin operator in the $\gamma$-direction.
